# Custom hot drinks maker availability

Tags: brewing-process, coffee-machines

I am interested in finding out if the following product exists, a custom hot drinks maker e.g. User adds own ingredients, such as blended coffee beans, instant coffee granules, milk, teabags, sugar, and so on, then selects quantities of each ingredient to create custom hot drink (saved onto onboard memory).

This custom drink could then be accessed any time by the user E.g on selection menu Users > Connor > Morning Coffee.

It seems like a simple enough device that a product like this would be available to purchase, however I cant find any online.

I am looking for something like this as I like the idea of a hot drinks maker, however I want to continue drinking my favourite drinks, and not be limited to pre made sachets.

If anyone could fill me in on any information regarding the existence of such a product I would be extremely grateful, thank you.

Comment: I'm not too certain this question has anything but a "yes" or "no" answer. It might be easy to construct - but is there a market for it?  Most people that I know who like coffee and tea also like the process of making it. Smelling the tea / coffee as it comes out of storage, the smell of the grind and finally the smell of the final product.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are commercial automats (machines) that can prepare custom defined hot beverages from granules or beans. (I have never seen one that can properly brew tea, though.) They can add milk powder or milk. Furthermore, those automats can even put a stick to stir the sugar at the end. There exist also small sizes that can fit onto a kitchen desk.

However, I'm not sure if this is the gadget that you desire.